# joining multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have 2000 pandas dataframe stored. Size of each dataframe is (**X**,2) where **X** can be any positive integer above 100. For example:

```
##Dataframe 1

entry.          feature
entry1            716
entry2            373
entry3            837 

##Dataframe 2

entry.          feature
entry1            173
entry2             0
entry4            981
entry5            717

##Dataframe 2

entry.          feature
entry1            716
entry5            736
```

I want the final dataframe to look like:

```
##Dataframe 1

entry.          Dataframe1.        DataFrame2         Dataframe3
entry1            716                 173                716
entry2            373                  0                  0
entry3            837                  0                  0
entry4             0                  981                 0
entry5             0                  717                736
```

So what I want to achieve is that I want to join these data frames on the basis of entry column. And if a given entry is not present in a dataframe for example entry 2 is not present in dataframe 3 then I want to set the value as 0 there. How can I achieve this with 2000 data frames that I have? Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: how they are stored? in a dictionary? list?

Comment: it looks like your dataframes are rather Series, no?

Comment: All of my data frames are stored as csv files.

Comment: Is there a pattern in the file names? Please give some details

Comment: What do you mean by pattern?

Comment: Second column (feature column that is) becomes a new column in the final dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with the `axis=1` option to concatenate column-wise:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

If the data is stored in files on the disk, assuming they are named /tmp/dfXXX.csv, you use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/glob.html) module combined with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
from glob import glob

files = glob('/tmp/df*.csv') 
df = pd.concat({f: pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', index_col=0)['feature']
                for f in files}, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

output:

```
        /tmp/df1.csv  /tmp/df2.csv  /tmp/df3.csv
entry1           716           173           716
entry2           373             0             0
entry3           837             0             0
entry4             0           981             0
entry5             0           717           736
```

NB. I used `'\s+'` as a separator here, but this might be different depending on the actual separator of your csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.merge
df3_merged = pd.merge[df1, df2]

Even you can use left or right join.
df3_merged = pd.merge[df1, df2, how = 'left']